# Implementing custom return value in Authentication Service

Tags: c#, silverlight-5.0, wcf-ria-services

There is an Authentication Service that must notify the client to why the username and password is invalid. For example, its password may be expired. But the *Login* method in a authentication service should return a valid *IPrinciple* or null for anonymous users. This means that the following code will not work:

```cs
    public UserAuthBase Login(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, string customData)
    {

        var result = repository.Login(userName, password);

        if (result != null && !result.PasswordExpired)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(result.Name, true);
            // Some Code
        }
        else if (result != null)
        {
            return new UserAuthBase { Name = string.Empty, PasswordExpired = true };
        }

        return result;
    }
```

This code will throw **InvalidOperationException** with the message:

> The user must be authenticated when the Login finishes successfully

how can i change this approach to support any message for the client?!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question right, you can put try/catch around Login method to catch InvalidOperationException. Then you can show any message to user by your choise.

Comment: Thanks. Throwing DomainException was the first choice. But I went to support it without any exception. I forced to use exceptions...